# How to get iPad Unique Identifier from Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, ios, ipad

Any method to get an iPad unique identifier from website using .Net ?
(uniqueIdentifier property is Deprecated in iOS 5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique identifier was never sent as part of a http request header so it was never possible to get this info. If you want a unique ID for a device I would suggest you use a cookie to do it.